# How can I repeat this block of code?

Tags: ruby, string, search, replace, substring

I am a beginner programmer. My code, which is in Ruby, basically scans a text and finds the number of times a certain word appears or replaces words in the text. The first thing that I am unable to do is to repeat the block of code. If someone wants to rescan or replace their text they have to re-start the program instead of the program going on, I have tried solving this problem by taking the whole block of code and looping it but it didn't work and returned an error. The other thing is that whenever I use the replace function it only replaces one word as opposed to both. For example it shows food meme instead of food food in the image below: [image]

```
puts "insert your text: "
string = gets.chomp

puts "would you like to scan or replace your text?"
choice = gets.chomp

#this is the scan option which scans the text and outputs the amount of times a word is in it

if choice.include? "scan"

  puts "what word would you like to scan?"
  word_for_scan = gets.chomp
      scan_count = string.scan(word_for_scan).count
      puts "The word #{word_for_scan} appears #{scan_count} times"

#this is the replace function in the code which replaces the words in the text, as shown in the image above, whenever I try to replace something it only replaces one word instead of all of them

elsif choice.include? "replace"

  puts "what word would you like to replace?"
  word_for_replacement = gets.chomp
      puts "what word would you like to replace it with?"
      replacement_word = gets.chomp
        replaced_text = string.sub(word_for_replacement, replacement_word)
        puts "here is your new text: #{replaced_text}"

else
  puts "error: would you like to scan or replace text?"

end
```

Thanks for looking at the code and trying to solve the problem.

Comment: What does "it didn't work and returned an error" mean? *How exactly* "didn't it work"? What was the *precise* error message? Please provide a [mcve] and sample inputs and outputs for your desired outcomes, including any and all special cases and corner cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** **Answer to Question 1 recursive execution**:

Just **move the code into a `method/function`** and call the `same function` inside it.

This is called the concept `recursive function` and fulfills your requirement.

```
def changeText

  puts "insert your text: "
  string = gets.chomp

  puts "would you like to scan or replace your text?"
  choice = gets.chomp

  #this is the scan option which scans the text and outputs the amount of times a word is in it

  if choice.include? "scan"

    puts "what word would you like to scan?"
    word_for_scan = gets.chomp
        scan_count = string.scan(word_for_scan).count
        puts "The word #{word_for_scan} appears #{scan_count} times"

  #this is the replace function in the code which replaces the words in the text, as shown in the image above, whenever I try to replace something it only replaces one word instead of all of them

  elsif choice.include? "replace"

    puts "what word would you like to replace?"
    word_for_replacement = gets.chomp
        puts "what word would you like to replace it with?"
        replacement_word = gets.chomp
          replaced_text = string.sub(word_for_replacement, replacement_word)
          puts "here is your new text: #{replaced_text}"

  else
    puts "error: would you like to scan or replace text?"

  end
  changeText();
end  

changeText();
```

**2)** **Answer to Question 2 use `gsub` instead of `sub`**:

**`gsub` replaces all the instances, while `sub` replaces a single instance.**

`string.gsub(word_for_replacement, replacement_word)`

Comment: @Sarim Aleem, please check my answer.

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Just put a while loop around your code.

```
while true do
    puts "hello"
end
```

Control-C will exit the loop or you can do something more fancy with the input from the user.

You can replace all the instances in your string by using `gsub` instead of `sub`

Answer (score 1):

**How to make your program run over and over again**
If you are not familiar with `while` loops or defining functions, then please go ahead and read all about it. I don't want to spoil the fun of discovering what magic it can do for your programs. However, if you really need your program working right away without getting into details, check other answers, you'll find the correct code!

**How to replace all words**
You want to use `gsub` method instead of `sub` when substituting all instances of a given word:

```
    replaced_text = string.gsub(word_for_replacement, replacement_word)
```

`sub` substitutes one occurence of a word, while `gsub` is for global substitution (all occurrences).